# Что делать с потоками в которых было брошено необработанное исключение

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
this.threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                MIN_THREAD_POOL_SIZE, MAX_THREAD_POOL_SIZE,
                1, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                this.workQueue, this.threadFactory);
```

на нем я вызываю

```
 this.threadPoolExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }
    });
```

и это исключение у меня перехватывается в `UncaughtExceptionHandler`

```
class RequestExecutorUncaughtExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    private final String TAG = RequestExecutorUncaughtExceptionHandler.class.getSimpleName();
    private Log log = new Log(TAG);

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {

        log.error("Uncaught exception in thread [" + thread.getName() + "]",throwable);
    }
}
```

**Вопрос:** что делать дальше с потоком в котором был брошен `exception` вызывать `thread.interrupt()` или `ThreadPoolExecutor` сам сделает все что нужно?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первое: нет, с потоком ничего делать не нужно.

Второе: если вам не безразлична судьба той задачи, которую вы просите выполнить, то более правильный способ -- воспользоваться методом `submit()`. Он возвращает [`FutureTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html), который будет содержать в себе результат выполнения операции или возникшее исключение. Если во время выполнения задачи возникло исключение, то позже, при вызове метода `get()`, оно будет выброшено и обернуто в `ExecutorException`.

```
Future future = this.threadPoolExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
});

try {
    future.get();
}
catch (ExecutorException e) {
    // обработка
}
```

[Вкратце](https://habrahabr.ru/post/116363/):

> Метод `submit` также возвращает объект `Future`, который содержит
>   информацию о статусе исполнения переданного `Runnable` или `Callable`
>   (который может возвращать значение). Из него можно узнать выполнился
>   ли переданный код успешно, или он еще выполняется. Вызов метода get на
>   объекте `Future` возвратит значение, который возвращает `Callable`
>   (или `null`, если используется `Runnable`). Метод имеет 2
>   checked-исключения: `InterruptedException`, который бросается, когда
>   выполнение прервано через метод `interrupt()`, или
>   `ExecutionException` если код в `Runnable` или `Callable` бросил
>   `RuntimeException`, что решает проблему поддержки исключений между
>   потоками.

Comment: а в случае если я буду часто вызывать метод submit и после этого вызывать future.get() - который как я понимаю блокирующий - это может сказаться на производительности?

Comment: @KirillStoianov может. Но все зависит от вашего сценария. Что делать -- тоже зависит от сценария. Возможно стоит посмотреть на `CompletableFuture`/`CompletionService`.